# How should the HTML lang attribute be formatted in terms of case and delimiter?

Tags: html5, case-sensitive, delimiter, lang-attribute

Consider these 4 codes:

- `lang="fa-ir"`
- `lang="fa-IR"`
- `lang="fa_ir"`
- `lang="fa_IR"`

Which one is correct? I can't seem to find documentation for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the w3c, the HTML lang attribute is in [BCP 47 format](https://www.w3.org/International/core/langtags/rfc3066bis.html).   That format is specified by [RFC 4646](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4646.txt).

As for hyphens vs underscores, the **hyphen** is the correct delimiter.  From section 2.1 of the RFC:

> The language tag is composed of one or more parts, known as
> "subtags".  Each subtag consists of a sequence of alphanumeric
> characters.  Subtags are distinguished and separated from one another
> by a hyphen ("-", ABNF [RFC4234] %x2D).

As far as case sensitivity, they are **case insensitive**.  From the RFC:

> The tags and their subtags, including private use and extensions, are
> to be treated as case insensitive: there exist conventions for the
> capitalization of some of the subtags, but these MUST NOT be taken to
> carry meaning.
>
> For example:
>
> - [ISO639-1] recommends that language codes be written in lowercase('mn' Mongolian).
> - [ISO3166-1] recommends that country codes be capitalized ('MN' Mongolia).
> - [ISO15924] recommends that script codes use lowercase with the initial letter capitalized ('Cyrl' Cyrillic).
>
> However, in the tags defined by this document, the uppercase US-ASCII
> letters in the range 'A' through 'Z' are considered equivalent and
> mapped directly to their US-ASCII lowercase equivalents in the range
> 'a' through 'z'.

So either `lang="fa-ir"` or `lang="fa-IR"` is correct but **`lang="fa-IR"`** is recommended.